# Google App Engine not able to show images and css

Tags: php, css, image, google-app-engine

I am new to GAE and trying to deploy my php application on it but when i open main.php in browser it donot show any css and images .

my **directory sttructure** is

[image: Directory Structure]

my **app.yaml**

```
application: blogakash
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.php

- url: /install_ubuntu.php
  script: install_ubuntu.php

- url: /install_virtualbox.php
  script: install_virtualbox.php

- url: /install_xampp.php
  script: install_xampp.php

- url: /tutorials.php
  script: tutorials.php


- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /css
  static_dir: css
```

and my **logs**

```
   2014-07-29 22:27:36 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=9080', '--admin_port=8001', u'E:\\Software\\gae\\blogakash']"
INFO     2014-07-29 22:27:39,638 devappserver2.py:671] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2014-07-29 22:27:39,653 api_server.py:341] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2014-07-29 22:27:39,667 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: http://localhost:57015
INFO     2014-07-29 22:27:39,674 dispatcher.py:171] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:9080
INFO     2014-07-29 22:27:40,480 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8001
INFO     2014-07-29 22:28:35,926 module.py:612] default: "GET /main.php HTTP/1.1" 200 812
INFO     2014-07-29 22:28:57,207 module.py:612] default: "GET /css/design.css HTTP/1.1" 200 812
INFO     2014-07-29 22:28:57,413 module.py:612] default: "GET /images/dp.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 812
INFO     2014-07-29 22:29:25,967 module.py:612] default: "GET /main.php HTTP/1.1" 200 812
INFO     2014-07-29 22:29:47,345 module.py:612] default: "GET /css/design.css HTTP/1.1" 200 812
INFO     2014-07-29 22:29:47,417 module.py:612] default: "GET /images/dp.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 812
INFO     2014-07-29 22:30:17,378 module.py:612] default: "GET /tutorials.php HTTP/1.1" 200 812
INFO     2014-07-29 22:30:38,638 module.py:612] default: "GET /css/design.css HTTP/1.1" 200 812
INFO     2014-07-29 22:30:38,815 module.py:612] default: "GET /images/dp.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 812
INFO     2014-07-29 22:36:03,042 module.py:612] default: "GET /tutorials.php HTTP/1.1" 200 812
INFO     2014-07-29 22:36:24,342 module.py:612] default: "GET /css/design.css HTTP/1.1" 200 812
INFO     2014-07-29 22:36:24,540 module.py:612] default: "GET /images/dp.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 812
INFO     2014-07-29 22:36:24,559 module.py:612] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2014-07-29 22:39:00,559 module.py:612] default: "GET /tutorials.php HTTP/1.1" 200 812
INFO     2014-07-29 22:39:21,766 module.py:612] default: "GET /css/design.css HTTP/1.1" 200 812
INFO     2014-07-29 22:39:22,053 module.py:612] default: "GET /images/dp.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 812
INFO     2014-07-29 22:39:22,066 module.py:612] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2014-07-29 22:40:44,042 api_server.py:538] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2014-07-29 22:40:44,042 api_server.py:541] Saving search indexes
2014-07-29 22:40:44 (Process exited with code 0)
```

GAE is unable to upload my css and images.I am unable to understand what the log says.I have also searched the similar threads on stack tried most of it but dint get any output.

**Am i missing something in installation or configuration ?**

Thanks.

Comment: what is "unable to show"? All the images you have in your pages show up as 404? that'd imply your urls are wrong, or the images are not on the server where they should be.

Comment: finally solved it replaced  `.* `to  `/` in `- url: .*
  script: main.php` thanks to @MarcB for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: The order of url handler matters in app.yaml. Having .* as your first rule will basically matches all URLs and render remaining handlers useless.